# Passing an object method to an external function in python

Tags: python, methods

Ok, so the task Im trying to accomplish is a bit dense to post in full here, but Ive written an example that shows what Im trying to do.

```
import random


class Dog:
    def __init__(self, height, weight, length, age):
        self.Height = height
        self.Weight = weight
        self.Length = length
        self.Age = age

    def getAge(self):
        return self.Age

    ## the real version would have a lot more methods that return the
    ## stats for this object




def getStatMean(doggies, statCall):
    output = 0.0


    for dog in doggies:
        output += dog.statCall() 
    output /= float(len(doggies))

    return output




if(__name__ == "__main__"):
    doggies = []
    for i in range(0, 100):
        doggies.append(Dog(10, 20, 30, random.random()*10))

    print getStatMean(doggies, Dog.getAge)
```

essentially my problem is that I have a list of objects. These objects all have a large number of stat calls that I am looking to manipulate in the same way (in this case calculate a mean, but the actual example is more complex).

The simplest way of doing this would be to write a getStatMean function for each one of the methods that the object has, but this starts to grow out of control as I add more and more methods to the object. I want to be able to pass the method name to one function, and call the method name that was passed on each object like in the example.

When I try to run the snippet posted above, I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "example.py", line 39, in
>   
>       print getStatMean(doggies, Dog.getAge)   File "example.py", line 26, in getStatMean
>       output += dog.statCall()  AttributeError: Dog instance has no attribute 'statCall'

Is what I am trying to do possible in python, or am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIrst of all : methods of instance are named **methods** because they are in fact **bound function** thats mean python is automatically passing to them it first param which is instance on which You call them. So if you are acessing method from class You must provide this *self* by yourself. 
And use just function without class. 
so call should look like this :

```
output += statCall(dog)
```

Comment: So simple. How did I miss this, hahaha.

Thank You